# Common signal line

Tags: gpio

I already have a solution for how to prevent polling for RS485 ([question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/386225/how-to-prevent-polling-using-rs485)), however since I will eventually maybe have quite some devices and like a fast latency, I think I rather want an extra 'polling/signal' line.

- I have 3 to 20+ (?) devices.
- I want the best 'latency' i.e. when a device wants to send something, it needs to be send as soon as possible (the message is mostly very small).

Idea:

- The device that wants the RS485 token sets a signal line HIGH.
- This signal is connected to all devices (like the RS485 RX/TX).
- The 'Master' reads it and polls all devices (it does not know who sent the signal)
- When the slave device has the token, it sends its data and sets the signal LOW.

My question:

Can I use this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu4VX3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Questions:

1. I assume the diodes are 'mandatory' ?
2. I will use probably 3.3V MCUs (STM32). What if 10 devices starts putting their GPIO_Output high? Will this cause problems?
3. Should I also connect the signal line to all devices with a GPIO_Input and not send it HIGH when it is already HIGH? Although I don't like a software solution that can ruin my STM32s.
4. The complete length of the cable is approximately 1 meter/yard... All devices will be next to each other somewhat.

Comment: What are your timing constraints? I would just keep passing the token all the time. With a single "token request" line the master still has to ask every device on the bus to figure out which one wants the token. Moreover - if the total bus length is 1m then a naked UART will work just fine (if you have enough UARTs in the master).

Comment: Why not an open-collector system with a pull-up resistor? You can realize this low-cost with a GPIO (output `0` for active, switch to input for inactive), or with a transistor in between to protect the MCU.

Comment: Another option would be to monitor the bus, and if it is idle (i.e. the master is in power-save mode), force a break condition.

Comment: @filo in principle the fastest solution, for polling e.g. 20 devices and assuming polling takes 20 us (?) it would be 400 us. But if every device has to reply to some useless message every 400 us (or preferably faster) it also takes time it cannot use for something else.

Comment: @SimonRichter I would have to check into an open-collector system, I don't think I used this (and not sure what it means, but I can google it). Thanks

Comment: @SimonRichter I use DC adapter so was not planning for power-save mode, but still the line can be idle of course... but what do you mean with forcing a break condition?

Comment: @MichelKeijzers, a "break" means sending a long invalid frame. In RS-232, that is a long `SPACE`, which looks like a start bit, a byte and an invalid stop bit. The receiver detects the invalid stop bit and starts a timer, and if it still receives `SPACE` at the end of that, it signals the OS. If your RS485 frames also have start and stop bits, then you can use this circuitry to send an interrupt that wakes up the receiver — so you can have the master go to power-save and wake it up with a "break".

Comment: @SimonRichter I would have to check how to wake up (or do something) when an invalid RS485 frame would come in (probably via the default UART interrupt). I am using STM32's (no OS).

Comment: @SimonRichter the open drain is maybe easy, since the STM32's GPIO's have already open drain and pullups (it cannot hurt to connect multiple GPIOs with pullups together?)

Comment: I’m not understanding “the idea”. Poor me!

Comment: @Andyaka I tried to update my question.

Comment: It seems to me that polling (potentially) all devices to see who is requesting the token is going to take a long time. How many bits in a master poll is needed? What data rate is being used?

Comment: @Andyaka I hope to use 2.5 mbps, and only need a few bytes for a poll (and some ACK), so let's say 32 bits per device, times 20 = 640 bits, which would take 256 us (probably more because of some overhead/start/stop bit).

Comment: ....You might just as well do regular polls to all slaves as per conventional RS485. The only benefit of an extra line could be to short-cut the full poll of all slaves by having a background time slot system as per the earlier answer I gave.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid regular polling from the master - is that what you are trying to achieve? I.e. only start a master poll when the common signal line is activated?

Comment: @Andyaka Well I already was planning for using a specific device (let's call it Master) in case I have to poll continuously. So than it does not matter for that device to be busy a lot.

Comment: Then if that is the case AND you have to poll to find out who requested the token, what is the benefit of having the common line rather than just continually polling like standard master slave comms systems?

Comment: @Andyaka you are right ... the only benefit I can now think of is the 'handling' of the 'empty polling' messages all the time. But if there are many messages there is also a lot of unnecessary polling in my csae, and in case there are less messages, timing will be not an issue anyway.

Comment: You could get a benefit with the extra line if you wanted to avoid data polling continually --->  because you can transfer the timeslot arbitration to this new common line and have it running while messages are being sent thus saving 20 slots for slave detection occupying the main data bus. Just a thought.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes that might be a good idea ... but than it gets rather complicated (for me) (but I also started the question). Thank you very much for thinking with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my recommendation for what it's worth.

If you have to poll all the slaves to set up a token for a particular slave so that it, in turn, can send its message, you might as well just continually poll all the slaves as per a conventional master slave system.

This also can work peer-to-peer because all slaves can read all other master and slave data and directly respond (if needed) to the slave that originates the message. The originating slave would still send its message when polled by the master.

This could mean that once the prospective-originating slave is polled by the master, it can take control of the bus and directly address-target a message to another slave. When this happens the targetted slave can respond directly to the originating slave OR, it can wait until *its* master poll arrives before replying. It's called *protocol design*.

*In the [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/386225/how-to-prevent-polling-using-rs485) a peer-to-peer system was discussed where one device (call it a master) set up a system of time slots; one for each other device. The nth device would wait for the nth time slot and if all previous time slots were inactive, it would initiate a message. The down side of this is that 20 timeslots takes up room on what might be busy periods and thus overall payload rate may suffer.*

If you do wish to use a common line, the timeslot arbitration process (discussed in the previous question) could be relagated from the main bus to this secondary bus and arbitration could, theoretically take place duing regular transmissions of data on the main bus.

Comment: Thank you for this great 'summary' of all solutions. I would have to check which solution works best, but it is good, even the arbitration overhead can be prevented by using a secondary line.

Comment: If you need direct communication between devices, at some point it may make sense to just use CAN.

Comment: @SimonRichter and there lies the crux of the question. Try and retrace back through Michel's questions.